# Javascript - Converting object to array with object.values

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am returning an object that holds an array of data that I am attempting to access. I in return used the `object.values` method to convert this invalid object into a 2D array. From here I am able to loop and apply my javascript to the data that is being returned. My issue is that `Object.values` is not compatible with legacy browsers which I am attempting to accommodate. Is there an alternative I can use other than object.values to convert remove the original object?

For example :

```
const data = {[ ["Online Stores", 2, 3453], ["Retail Stores", 1 , 46643] ]}

const newData = Object.values(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...in` with a `hasOwnProperty` check.

```js
delete Object.values;//for testing purposes
Object.values = Object.values || function(obj){
  console.log("Fallback implementation");
  var arr = [];
  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) arr.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return arr;
}
var obj = {a: 1, b: '2', c: {d: 4}};
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object has syntax error but considering it has objects with keys you could use a `for in` loop here an use `flat()` to flatten the array one level here is an example

```js
const data = {
  0: [
    ["Online Stores", 2, 3453],
    ["Retail Stores", 1, 46643],
  ],
};

newData = [];
for (let key in data) {
  newData.push(data[key]);
}
console.log(newData.flat());
```